# How do I find the probability of these two events?

Tags: probability

So let's say I know that $P(A) = 450/700$, $P(B) = 275/700$, and $P(A~\text{and}~B^c) = 375/700$. So I'm trying to find $P(A^c \mid B)$. I know that $A^c$ is $250/700$ and I know how to find $P(A^c \mid B)$, but I'm not sure what $P(A^c \cap B)$ is. To find that, you need to add the probabilities of $A^c$ and $B$ together and then subtract the intersection. The problem is I'm not sure what the intersection is supposed to be. Does anyone know what it could be given the above information.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a Venn Diagram; $S$ is universal set; $A$ and $B$ are two sets present in it
Let $S$ has $700$ elements.
[image]

Now what you need is Probability of $A^c$. If $B$ has already happened, then
$$P(A^c|B) = \frac{P(A^c \cap B)}{P(B)}= \frac{200/700}{275/700} = \frac{200}{275}=\frac{8}{9}.$$

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Your work is correct until the final step.  What do you get when you reduce $\frac{200}{275}$?